# Dataframe string slicing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a Dataframe which contains a column where the values are:

- abc_0.1
- aabbcc_-0.010
- qwerty_0.555

How can I use the lambda function to transform the column values into simply numeric values:

- 0.1
- -0.010
- 0.555

Comment: I'm not sure a lambda would be needed here: `df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace(r'^[^0-9.]*','')` or whatever regex makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with the regex `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$` and optionally convert [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df['num'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'].str.extract(r'(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$', expand=False))
```

output:

```
             col    num
0        abc_0.1  0.100
1  aabbcc_-0.010 -0.010
2   qwerty_0.555  0.555
```

Regex:

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EY508w/1)

```
-?          # optionally match a - sign
\d+         # match one or more digits
(?:\.\d+)?  # optionally match a dot and digit(s)
$           # match end of string
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question ?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [
    'abc_0.1',
    'aabbcc_-0.010',
    'qwerty_0.555',
]})
df['col'] = df['col'].str.extract(r'[a-zA-Z]+_(.*)').astype(float)
df
```

```
    col
0   0.100
1   -0.010
2   0.555
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#extract a group comprising of any digit, period or a minus sign, occurring one or more times

df['text'].str.extract(r'([\d\.\-]+)' )
```

```
0
0   0.1
1   -0.1
2   0.555
```